# How to achieve below using Abinitio component?

Tags: ab-initio

My Input is something like below:

fieldname

> Anusha

My requirement to get the output as follows:

fieldname

> A An Anu Anus Anush Anusha

Answer (score 0):

GDE 4.x

One of the way: to use 'Transform/Reformat' (Transform/Reformat recordset) component.

Inside Transform/Reformat Component, you have to use String function to split Input data to data you need..

Did you asked AbInitio support about it?

Answer (score 0):

If that is true then

Use normalize component

Specify the length as string_lenght(in.field_name);

and in normalize function write as

out.field_name :: string_substring(in.field_name,1,index);

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
out::reformat(in)=
begin
    out.str :: funny_string(in.str);
end;

out :: funny_string(str) =
begin
    let int i;
    let string("\n") s="";
    for(i,i<length_of(str))
        s = s + " "+string_substring(str,1,i+1);
    out :: s;
end;
```